# How can I attach an html5 file on outlook without changing it's encoding?

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, outlook

I'm trying to send an email with an html5 file attached to it. The problem is that when I open the file with Outlook, the encoding changes from utf-8 to another configuration, once it has some text in brazilian portuguese written in the file it's very important to have the proper encoding.

Is it possible to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your code that attaches the HTML file? Does it already exist on the file system? Or do you create it?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I created the code

Comment: So if you save on the file system, can it be successfully opened in a browser?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko yes, I tested the file in Google Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge and it worked just fine. The problem I am having is that I have to sent the file by email to another person. When I attach the email and the person who receives the massage has an gmail, the file in downloaded and it works well, but when the massage is sent to a person that has an outlook email, once the file is downloaded the charset changes and because of that the html becomes unreadable.

Comment: You really need to post the relevant snippets of the original and modified HTML files